# Sequential plotting of ggplots similar to par(mfrow = ...)?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Is there a way to interactively and sequentially add more ggplots onto a plotting window, similar to how in `base` you can add more plots by using `par(mfrow = ...)`. E.g. (for loop to simulate sequentially entering plot commands):

```
par(mfrow = c(4, 1))

for (i in 1:4) {
    plot(tmp_df$x, tmp_df$y)
}
```

produces, sequentially, the first to the last row of the following plot:

[image]

Whereas, doing the same with `ggplot` just prints one plot to the plot window:

```
par(mfrow = c(4, 1))

for (i in 1:4) {
    plot(ggplot(tmp_df, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_point())

}
```

I already know how to use `gridExtra::grid.arrange` to arrange a list of `ggplots`, e.g.:

```
tmp_list <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
    tmp_list[[length(tmp_list) + 1]] <-
        ggplot(tmp_df, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_point()

}

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = tmp_list, nrow = 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly add one plot at a time e.g by making a grid layout and drawing in specific viewports sequentially,

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

gl <- replicate(4, ggplot(), F)

par <- function(mfrow = c(2,2)) pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(mfrow[1], mfrow[2])))
print.gg <- function(x) {
  rc <- which(matrix(1:4, 2, 2) == ii, arr.ind = TRUE)
  ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x, vp=viewport(layout.pos.row = rc[1,1], layout.pos.col = rc[1,2]))
  ii <<- (ii+1)%%4
}

grid.newpage()
par()
for(ii in seq_along(gl))
  print(gl[[ii]])
```

Comment: a core concept of grid graphics is that graphical objects (grobs) should not assume that they own the entire device, but rather, try to play nice with other elements in separate viewports. In that sense, it's not as straightforward to place a ggplot in divided layouts because grid viewports are much more versatile than base layouts and therefore require more verbose arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with a gtable layout keeping track of occupied cells,

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)


par <- function(mfrow=c(2,2)) {
  nr <- mfrow[1]; nc <- mfrow[2]
  .g_layout <<- gtable(widths = unit(rep(1/nc, nc), "npc"), heights = unit(rep(1/nr, nr), "npc"))
}

print.gg <- function(x) {
  ntot <- prod(dim(.g_layout))
  ii <- (length(.g_layout) + 1) %% (ntot+1)
  rc <- which(matrix(seq_len(ntot), nrow = nrow(.g_layout), ncol = ncol(.g_layout)) == ii, arr.ind = TRUE)
  .g_layout <<- gtable::gtable_add_grob(.g_layout, ggplotGrob(x), t = rc[1,1], l = rc[1,2])
  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(.g_layout)
}


gl <- replicate(4, ggplot(), F)

par()
for(ii in seq_along(gl))
  print(gl[[ii]])
```

Comment: do these override the functionality in base `par`?

Comment: yes, it's probably a good idea to use different names. `rm(par); rm(print.gg)` will remove them safely from your session.